# Adding Background Image to Windows 8 App

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

I'm currently designing a Windows 8 App and I'm wondering how to draw a background on the main page, right after the splash screen. I'm using JavaScript to create this app, and I have not found any tutorials or help for just drawing/displaying a simple background image. I am very new to web-based programming languages so if you could provide a tutorial, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There is a free e-book that covers everything about writing windows 8 apps with JS, take a look at it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2012/10/29/free-ebook-programming-windows-8-apps-with-html-css-and-javascript.aspx)

Comment: keune, thanks for the link. I've actually taken a look at that book. I tried the methods that it explained in there, but when my application launched, it showed my splash screen, then crashed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<body style="background-image: url('/images/ff-background.jpg');">` inside of default.html or you can use css to the **body** tag.